# Jasmine loadFixtures is not defined?

Tags: jasmine

I followed the tutorial on > http://railscasts.com/episodes/261-testing-javascript-with-jasmine <.
but i get the error message -> ReferenceError: loadFixtures is not defined in spec/credit_card_spec.js">http://localhost:8888/**spec**/credit_card_spec.js .

I don´t now how i could solve these problem. could anyone help me.

Comment: Can you go a little bit more into detail as to how you got this issue resolved?  What was originally in the helper file and what you added/removed to make it work?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the test helper file helpers/jasmine-jquery-1.3.1.js doesn't contain some functions, so i downloaded it again and i works.

Don't forget, also you need a jQuery helper file.